# Dropping rows from a table with condition check - SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

There is a table 'collection' which has the following columns - id, cid , cname, cdescription, isviewed.

Every time I get value from server, I refresh this table by dropping all the rows and insert new values from server. I need to add an exception here - If column cname starts with '/mnt/sdcard', I do not want to delete those rows, rest all the rows should be deleted. Is this achievable using a single query in sqlite?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `where` clause to `delete`:

```
delete from collection
    where cname not like '/mnt/sdcard%';
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I will accept this as the right answer. Still, the delete and insert queries has to work seperate, correct?

Comment: @user899412 . . . The inserts and deletes would be done in separate statements.